# Android FTP inputstream into XML

Tags: android, xml, ftp

Hi im trying to read a XML-file from a FTP-server and parse it.

But im not able to use my string as inputsource. I can see that im able to read the file in the LogCat and I can open the XMl-file in my browser. But Im unsure how to use the string as an inputsource.

CODE:

```
public void readXML(){

    try {
        Log.e("FTP", "Starting ftp session");

        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

        Log.e("FTP", "Connecting to FTP");
        ftp.connect("ftp.domain.com");

        Log.e("FTP", "Providing credentials to FTP");
        ftp.login("user", "pswd");
        if(ftp.login("user", "pswd")){
            Log.e("FTP", "Was able to connect to FTP");
        }

        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/folder/XML");

        Log.e("FTP", "Getting stream");
        InputStream inStream = ftp.retrieveFileStream("file.xml");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF8");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String Input = "";
        Log.e("FTP", "Reading filestream");

        do{
            Input = Input + reader.readLine() + "\n";
            Log.e("FTP", reader.readLine());

        }while(reader.readLine()!=null);            

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Log.e("FTP", "Parsing inputsource");
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(Input)));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Log.e("FTP", "Creating nodelist");
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TAG");
```

Im unsure if StringReader is the correct way to go.

EDIT:

Thanks to Rajesh

This is my solution:

```
public void readXML(){

    try {
        Log.e("FTP", "Starting ftp session");

        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

        Log.e("FTP", "Connecting to FTP");
        ftp.connect("ftp.domain.com");

        Log.e("FTP", "Providing credentials to FTP");
        ftp.login("user", "pswd");
        if(ftp.login("user", "pswd")){
            Log.e("FTP", "Was able to connect to FTP");
        }

        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/folder/XML");

        Log.e("FTP", "Getting stream");
        InputStream inStream = ftp.retrieveFileStream("file.xml");          

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Log.e("FTP", "Parsing inputsource");
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(inStream));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Log.e("FTP", "Creating nodelist");
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TAG");
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? If so, please post it. Creating `InputSource` from `StringReader` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions / observations:

1. You can create `InputSource` directly from the `InputStream` without having an intermediate `String`
2. Instead of creating a `String` by appending `String`s multiple times, it would be efficient to use `StringBuffer`
3. Using the following code will result in skipping of alternate lines (and possibly invalid XML - it may be **the** problem in your case)

   ```
   do{
       Input = Input + reader.readLine() + "\n";
       Log.e("FTP", reader.readLine());

   }while(reader.readLine()!=null);
   ```

Comment: THANKS!
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(inStream));